# DSE spark cluster on AWS worker and Executor ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I am trying to setup a 6 node DSE 5.1 spark cluster on AWS EC2 machines.
I have referred the DSE documentation 
just to start with, I have opened `all TCP` ports , when I checked the logs, I found that worker process and executor process and driver process are using below ports

```
33xxx
33xxx
33xxx
34xxx
34xxx
34xxx
35xxx
35xxx
35xxx
36xxx
37xxx
37xxx
39xxx
40xxx
40xxx
41xxx
41xxx
43xxx
43xxx
43xxx
43xxx
45xxx
46xxx
```

the range here is from 33xxx to 46xxx, what is suggested range to open the ports ?, or is there any way to bind worker and executor ports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the port selection is random

See [the Spark Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking)

Specifically

```
spark.blockManager.port
spark.driver.port
```

While you can lock these down to a specific value by setting them in the `SparkConf` or on the CLI through Spark Submit, you need to make sure that every application has *unique* values so they do not collide.

In most cases it makes sense to keep the Driver in the same VPN as the Cluster.

Comment: Thank you @RussS, is there any way to fix the executor and worker ports ?or can we define ranges ?

Comment: 1. Yes see answer.
2. No